# Are moderators responding to flags?

Tags: support, flagging

I've flagged several questions, answers, and comments.

Some of these have been subsequently closed, deleted, or amended; but I don't see any response to my flags.

Are moderators responding to flags?

**EDIT Nov 20th, 2013:** My flag weight is very high, but for some reason, no action has been taken on my flags.

Is the code broken again?

Comment: Yes. The flag queue is currently empty on the main site, and I am in the process of taking care of the one flag on meta. Is there any post in particular you think needs some action?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've managed to hit the elusive "flag hell-ban": the majority of your flags have been declined, causing the system to no longer trust you to flag appropriately... As a consequence of this, it deletes your flags rather than showing them to moderators.

We'll be [re-working the behavior of this system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban) soon.

Comment: This is not *entirely* accurate. The flags can still be seen (via user's flagging history or by directly visiting the post; and are visible in the queue, but only when there are other flags on the same post), but can't be handled in any way.

Comment: Yeah, you can see them the same way you can see other deleted flags, @Jim - but normally you do have to go looking for them.

Comment: @Shog9 - Just curious - Any progress on this front? I've found quite a few comments today which need to be cleaned up.

Comment: It'll be a few weeks yet 'til the new system is rolled out, @Jim. For now, we've reset your flag weight (to half the default) - so you can flag again, if you make 'em good.

Answer (score 3):

**Response to Nov 20th edit:**

Your active flags are on a post we're still keeping an eye on.  You should probably see those cleared out in the next day or so.

If you see flags sitting in the active state, it's generally because we're watching to see how something plays out or haven't yet decided what action to take or even if action is required.

An example would be a not an answer flag where we suspect there's a chance someone is very likely to edit and improve the post, which saves us from having to delete it.